# In android studio AVD emulator doesn’t start

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with avd emulator. It wont start, I try everything and it still doesn't work. Here is the problem:

```
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: no program
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: no program
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: no program
```

Comment: AVD is very slow. Use Genymotion instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable virtualization from boot menu, I hope then your problem might be solved.